# UILabel with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation based on Orientation? (ARC, Storyboard, LLDB)

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.2, uiimagepickercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I had asked this question once before but has had 0 attention and the person helping me has not responded in weeks, so please forgive me but I still do need help.

Im working with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to flip a UILabel 180 degrees, I want the rotation based on UIOrientationPortrait and UIOrientationPortraitUpsideDown. I get 1/2 the result: when users flip to upside down (from portrait) the label transforms 180 and turns upside down as well (still facing the home button [Important])

BUT

when I rotate it back to Portrait the label stays in the flipped rotation state and does not stay with the home button. Thats what I need help with....

Here is the code i have:

```
#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)

...

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    TranslateLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(180));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rotating it upside down no matter what the orientation is. If you want it to rotate differently depending on the orientation, you have to do something like this:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
  switch(toInterfaceOrientation){
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
      TranslateLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
      break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
      TranslateLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(180));
      break;
  }
}
```

That way, it will rotate the label upside down when the device is upside down and it will return it back to normal when the device is on portrait orientation.

Comment: this worked but i had to add         case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            break; so an enumeration error would go away.

Comment: You can also add a default, which will be executed if none of the above happens, so you don't have to add every single case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to switch on `toInterfaceOrientation`, setting the transform as you have above if the orientation is `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` and to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` when it's `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`. (This assumes you don't allow rotations to the other orientations.)